# Como puedo acumular un dato por periodo de tiempo

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, group-by

Tengo un dataframe con fecha y hora en la que se creo la consulta para distintos items.

Quiero realizar una consulta que agrupe por fecha y hora sin importar que los items sean diferentes para luego poder graficar la cantidad de sesiones en esos periodos de tiempo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Intentaste algo?

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero emplear la librería *lubridate* para dar formato a la variable de fecha y hora que estés empleando y la librería *tidyverse* para agrupar tus datos mediante la instrucción *group_by()*. Una vez agrupados, puedes emplear la instrucción *summarise(n())* para realizar la cuenta de elementos por fecha y hora. Te recomiendo revisar el capítulo 16 del libro R para Ciencia de Datos disponible aquí: https://es.r4ds.hadley.nz/fechas-y-horas.html. A continuación te dejo un ejemplo reproducible, esperando que te sea de utilidad.

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Obtenemos la hora
flights$hora_vuelo = hour(flights$time_hour)

# Obtenemos la fecha
flights$fecha_vuelo = date(flights$time_hour)

# Ahora podemos emplear las variables creadas para agrupar y contar

# Para fecha
flights %>% group_by(fecha_vuelo) %>% summarise(num_vuelos = n()) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=num_vuelos, x=fecha_vuelo)) + geom_line()

# Para hora
flights %>% group_by(hora_vuelo) %>% summarise(num_vuelos = n()) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=num_vuelos, x=hora_vuelo)) + geom_line()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]